# laravel livewire, data not updated before render but it's updated after render

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-livewire

so i have group of components to control the quantity of each product, and each change of quantity i emit "quantityChanged" event to store in array (named 'cart') the product id and the new quantity. when i `dump` the array it shows that the array holds just the last product id and quantity, and since it shows just the last update i cant calculate the total price, but when i print it with `json_encode()` it shows all the elements of the array.

the quantity class:

```
class ProductQuantity extends Component
{
    public $product;
    public $quantity = 0;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.site.product-quantity');
    }


    public function updatedQuantity()
    {
        $this->emit('quantityChanged', $this->product->id, $this->quantity);
    }

    public function calcPrice () {
        return $this->quantity*$this->product->price;
    }
    
}
```

the total price class:
`

```
class TotalPrice extends Component
{
    public $totalPrice;
    public array $cart = [];
    protected $listeners = ["quantityChanged", "updateTotalPrice"];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.site.total-price');
    }

    public function quantityChanged($productId, $quantity)
    {
        $this->cart [$productId] = $quantity;
        dd($this->cart);
        $this->totalPrice = $this->calcTotalPrice();
    }

    public function calcTotalPrice(){
        $price = 0;
        try {
            foreach ($this->cart as $key => $quantity) {
                $price =+ Product::find($key)->price * $quantity;
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            abort(404);
        }
        return $price;
    }
}
```

[debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG1aS.png)

[when i dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1swPS.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231669/laravel-livewire-not-persisting-data-in-array-when-updating). It seems livewire has a bug when dumping arrays from the view in its functions. If you try and store it in the database or perhaps Log it instead of dumping it, you may get more favorable results.

Answer (score 0):

In your **TotalPrice** class you can make **selectedCartItems** listner like below and listen for items being emitted from **ProductQuantity** component.

```
class TotalPrice extends Component
{

    protected $listeners = [
        'selectedCartItems'
    ];


    public function selectedCartItems($selectedCartItems)
    {
        dd($selectedCartItems);
    }
}
```

and from your **ProductQuantity** component you emit selectedCartItem values array directly to the **TotalPrice** component.

```
class ProductQuantity extends Component
{
    public $cartItems = [];


    public function updatedQuantity()
    {
        $this->cartItems[$productId] = $quantity;

        $this->emitTo('total-price', 'selectedCartItems', $this->cartItems);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: hello, this works to get the new selected cart item, but i want to save all the selected items in array in **TotalPrice** called cart, the problem is that the data in this array do not persist and it holds the last item send by the last event, but i want all the items.